# Location Update in service

Tags: android, firebase, location, firebase-realtime-database

I'am trying to find the location of the user and update the value in my firebase database. But the location doesn't seem to be updated.I'am unable to identify the mistake. The service has started but the location doesn't seem to be updated.

My service is as follows:

```
public class MyLocation extends Service {

Firebase rootRef,child_ref;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

public MyLocation() {
    super();

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    rootRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
    child_ref = rootRef.child(rootRef.getAuth().getUid());

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            child_ref.setValue(location.getLatitude() + " : " + location.getLongitude());
            UserPojo userPojo=new UserPojo(location.getLatitude()+" : "+location.getLongitude());
            child_ref.child("location").setValue(userPojo);
            Log.i("location",location.getLatitude()+" : "+location.getLongitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
    try {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

My POJO class is as follows:

```
public class UserPojo {

String uname;
String email;
String location;


public UserPojo() {
}

public UserPojo(String uname, String email) {
    this.uname = uname;
    this.email = email;

}

public UserPojo(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
}
```

My service calling activity is as follows:

```
public class MembersListActivityFragment extends Fragment {
Intent intent;

private AuthData auth;

public MembersListActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_members_list, container, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        },10);
    }
Firebase firebase=new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
    auth=firebase.getAuth();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),auth.getUid(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




return rootView;
}


private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}







@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
           intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MyLocation.class);
            getActivity().startService(intent);

            boolean service_enabled= isMyServiceRunning(MyLocation.class);
            Log.i("service ",service_enabled+"");



        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
getActivity().stopService(intent);
}
}
```

My manifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".Family"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignInAcivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MembersListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_members_list"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <service android:name=".MyLocation" android:enabled="true"></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no checks at all to see if you have either GPS or Network location service available.

Also make sure you have the right permissions in the manifest.

This tutorial might help: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: I've already added the required permissions in the manifest file

Comment: This "tutorial" will not help!!!! `GPSTracker extends Service` and then `gps = new GPSTracker(this);` **is against basic android rules** (which is: **do not** create instance of Services, Activities, Applications classes by yourself with new operator)